# Edit Header's Border-Bottom length

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how could I set the border-bottom length of a header to a little bit longer than the text?
With this code it takes all the page length:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <h3 style="text-align:center; border-bottom:solid;">This is a test</h3>       
</div>
```

I've tried this code too:

```
<div style="position:relative;">    
        <h3 style="text-align:center;"><span style="border-bottom:solid;"> This is a test</span></h3>        
</div>
```

But with the last code it takes exactly the length of the text, how could I set the border-bottom length a little bit longer than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `padding` on the left & right on `<h3>`. Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.text-holder {
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-holder">
    <h3 class="text">This is a test</h3>       
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Add left/right padding on `<span>` to extend the borders.

```
h3 span {
  padding: 0 10px; /* Increase left/right padding to extend borders */
}
```

```html
<h3 style="text-align:center;">
   <span style="border-bottom:solid; padding: 0 10px;"> This is a test</span>
</h3>
```

***Note***: I don't like to use inline styles as they are considered as bad practice. I've shown this only as an idea for possible solution to your problem. Using an external style sheet is the best choice in most of the cases.